Animated particles object based on lifetime
For example, I have an object with shapekeys.This object is used as a particle.
How is it possible to animate this shape key depending on the lifetime of the particle?
Although, I am generally interested in the animation of the particle object depending on the lifetime of the particle. it's may be rotation, scaling, paremeter of modifiers.
In the material editor I can get the lifetime of the particle and get control over changing the material based on the lifetime of the particle. But how, for example, to make a particle changsng its shapekey in the first 20 frames of its life?
